# apache redirect / to subfolder

Tags: apache2

My application runs on https://example.com/app. I want to redirect https://example.com/ to https://example.com/app. My redirect rules in site conf are as below. How to modify it for my need?

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=PERMANENT]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **redirect** your clients (HTTP 301), try this:

```
# Redirect entire site ("/") without Query-Strings
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/app/
```

```
# Redirect all requests to "/" with Query-Strings
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC]
```

If you want to **rewrite** requests (internally):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Condition: Rewrite all URLS without app in them ...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/

# Condition:Rewrite all URLS from Domain ...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.

# Action: Rewrite to insert /app/<request>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1 [L]
```